# Find out all IP addresses of all Computers on Network

Tags: macos, mac, ip, terminal.app

I want to list all IP addresses with their Computer's names (if my IP was 197.577.52.4:  197.577.52.4 - Luca's MacBook) through Mac Terminal or Mac Software.

I tried many terminal commands, but it didn't really work.

Does anyone know a way to list all names and IP addresses?

Comment: Try `nmap` and `arp-scan`. But you will have to learn how to download and install extra software on your Mac., but you can do this only inside your own LAN.

Answer (score 2):

On linux I use `nmap` (https://nmap.org/), which is also available for Mac according to their website.

If I would want to list the all the devices on Linux, on the subnet 197.577.52.1, I would run

`sudo nmap -sP 192.577.52.1/24`

Comment: If anyone is wondering what does the option mean: -sP (Skip port scan) .
    This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available
    hosts that responded to the scan.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..254}
do
ping -W 1 -c 1 192.168.11.$i>/dev/null
done
arp -a|grep -v incomplete
```

Run the bash script to get all alive IP address on network. Change 192.168.11 with your network address.